# Compare all elements of two vectors for equality

Tags: r, vector, comparison, equality

I am trying a simple vector comparison between two vectors which are defined as follows:

```
pow_2 <- sapply(1:50, function(x) 2^x)
n_2   <- sapply(1:50, function(x) x^2)
```

I now need to compute the indices for which `pow_2[i] == n_2[i]` for some valid value of i.

For the time being, I wrote a function:

```
cat("\nPrinting indices which are identical for (n ^ 2) == (2 ^ n) - \n")

get_indices <- function() {
    for(i in 1:50) {
        for(j in 1:50) {
            if(pow_2[i] == n_2[j]) {
                cat(i)
                cat("\n")
            }
        }
    }
}

# call function:
get_indices()
```

When I try:

```
which(pow_2 == n_2)
```

it gives me indices 2 & 4 while skipping the rest.

Why isn't which() function telling about all indices?

Comment: ...because those are the only indices for which it's true: `2 ^ (1:50) == (1:50) ^ 2`

Comment: Do you want `which(pow_2 %in% n_2)`

Comment: @d.b YES!! Thanks! Where can I read more about %in% ?

Comment: @alistaire true

Comment: @alistaire not true. At least there are two more values. 2^6 = 8^2 and 2^8 = 16^2.

Comment: @arun type `?match` into your console and peruse the help file.

Comment: Really you want to see **`pow_2[i] == n_2[j]` for some valid values of i,j**. That's different to what you wrote. cc: @alistaire.